# Ajax Call from React to a PHP file - don't know location

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, api

Im creating a very basic login page and i'm trying to use php to verify the user login. Here is the code I'm using to access the php file.

```
 axios.post("login.php", {
    user: 'Fred',
    pass: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The PHP file is located within the src folder of the react app.

```
  ── src
    │   ├── components
    │   │   ├── BrowsePage
    │   │   │   ├── BrowsePage.css
    │   │   │   ├── BrowsePage.js
    │   │   │   └── default.jpg
    │   │   ├── CreatePage
    │   │   │   ├── CreatePage.css
    │   │   │   └── CreatePage.js
    │   │   ├── Header
    │   │   │   ├── Header.css
    │   │   │   └── Header.js
    │   │   ├── LoginPage
    │   │   │   ├── LoginPage.css
    │   │   │   ├── LoginPage.js
    │   │   │   └── logo.svg
    │   │   ├── ProfilePage
    │   │   │   ├── ProfilePage.css
    │   │   │   └── ProfilePage.js
    │   │   └── RecPage
    │   │       ├── default.jpg
    │   │       ├── RecPage.css
    │   │       └── RecPage.js
    │   ├── index.css
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── login.php
    │   └── registerServiceWorker.js
```

When I make the call it logs

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/login.php 404 (Not Found)
```

The current path to the php document does not work, and none of the others I've tried work. What is the path to make an axios call to this php document?

Comment: How are you serving these files currently? A request to a route that doesn't start with `/` is going to try to append it to the current url's path and make the request there. For example on this page, if you tried to make a request to `login.php`, it would result in a request to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645434/login.php`.

Comment: You have to configure your React code to proxy a php server that is running your login.php script. Are you using create-react-app or are you manually configuring a webpack config?

Comment: From the page http://172.22.94.194:3000/login, the log says xhr.js:178 POST http://172.22.94.194:3000/login.php 404 (Not Found) when i make a request. Also I'm using create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup a server locally that your React application can proxy certain http requests to. This server will run your login.php script and authenticate the username/password. `create-react-app` looks for a `proxy` value in your package.json and tells `webpack-dev-server` to forward any calls to `api/foobar` to wherever you have declared that your back-end will be running.

In your package.json add:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

This tells React to forward requests made to `http://localhost:3000/api/login` to `http://localhost:8000/api/login`

Then modify your axios call to look like this

```
axios.post("/api/login", ..., ...).then()
```

Next, you have to get your PHP server running on `http://localhost:8000` and set up your server application to handle POST requests made to `/api/login`.

I'm not a PHP guy but I've heard Laravel is nice to work with. It would be easier if your PHP backend was in its own directory completely.